# Request data by batch

Tags: c#, mongodb

I'm having a hard time trying to request data per batch.
First call to the API (Asp.Net core 2.2) I get a batch of 5 documents then on the second request I get the same documents. My question: how I can get the next batch ?

The idea is the web page shows the first 5 documents in a slideshow. When the user get to the end then a button apers asking if the user wants more data.

http://localhost:8000/all is the requestion url
the service method return a IAsynCursor.

Code:

```
var filter = new BsonDocument();
var options = new FindOptions<BsonDocument>
{
  // Get 5 docs at a time
  BatchSize = 5
};

using (var cursor = await _repo.FindAsync(filter, options))
{
  // Move to the next batch of docs
  while (await cursor.MoveNextAsync())
  {
    return cursor.Current;
  }
}
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: as an alternative, you can use the `Mongodb`'s Linq's `skip` and `limit` if pagination is what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: and the reason for your `cursor` returning the **same documents** is because on every request you are creating a new instance of the `cursor`(*as per the code you have shown*).

Comment: I thought so, NoCursorTimeout confused me. Thanks